# Calling torch.jit.trace on pytorch model yields class object name RuntimeError

Tags: python, pytorch, runtime-error, tensor

I am working on converting a pytorch model into a ScriptModule that save to a file and port over to C++.

When trying to trace the model in the code shown below, I get "**RuntimeError: Could not get name of python class object**."

```
from pathlib import Path

import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch import nn
from torch.nn.utils.rnn import pad_sequence, pack_padded_sequence
from .. import TORCH_DEVICE, __version_ft__, __version_train__

class LmkRNN(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, feature_size, hidden_size, out_size, n_layer=2, bf=False, bi=False):

        super(LmkRNN, self).__init__()

        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.n_layer = n_layer

        self.batch_size = 0
        self.max_seq_len = 0

        self.size_bl_out = feature_size * 2

        # n_direction = 2 if bi else 1
        # self.n_direction = n_direction
        self.n_direction = 1

        self.rnn_en = nn.GRU(input_size=self.size_bl_out, hidden_size=hidden_size,
                             num_layers=n_layer, batch_first=bf, bidirectional=bi)
        self.h_en = 0

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, out_size)

    def encoder(self, seq, seq_len, device):

        # seq: (max_seq_len, batch_size, n_pts, 2)
        max_seq_len, batch_size, n_pts, _ = seq.shape
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.max_seq_len = max_seq_len

        seq_c = torch.tanh(torch.flatten(seq, start_dim=-2))
        # seq_c: maxSeqLen, batchSize, self.size_bl_out
        packed = pack_padded_sequence(
            seq_c, seq_len, batch_first=False, enforce_sorted=False)

        self.h_en = torch.zeros(
            (self.n_layer, self.batch_size, self.hidden_size), device=device)
        out, h_n = self.rnn_en(packed, self.h_en)
        self.h_en = h_n


    #Main processor of the model
    def forward(self, seq, seq_len, device):
        self.encoder(seq=seq, seq_len=seq_len, device=device)
        enc = self.h_en[-1]
        out = self.fc1(enc)

        return F.normalize(out)
```

```
#Define the model parameters
n_lmk_pts = 476
hidden_size = 32
out_size = 64
n_layers = 2

FACE_EMB_SIZE = 512

device = torch.device(TORCH_DEVICE)

model_rnn = LmkRNN(feature_size=n_lmk_pts, hidden_size=hidden_size, out_size=out_size, n_layer=n_layers).to(
    device).float()
```

```
def compute_lmkemb(lmk_seq):
    print("In compute_lmkemb")
    with torch.no_grad():
        seq_len = [lmk_seq.shape[0], ]
        tensors = [torch.from_numpy(lmk_seq), ]
        ps = pad_sequence(tensors, batch_first=False)
        lmkdata = ps.float().to(device)
        emb = model_rnn(lmkdata, seq_len, device)

        #traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(func = LmkRNN(feature_size=n_lmk_pts, hidden_size=hidden_size, out_size=out_size, n_layer=n_layers).forward(seq = example, seq_len=seq_len, device=device), example_inputs=lmkdata)
        traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(model_rnn.forward(seq = lmkdata, seq_len=seq_len, device=device), example_inputs=lmkdata)


        # Serialize scriptmodule to a file.
        filename = "scriptmodule.pt"
        traced_script_module.save(filename)
        print(f"Successfully created scriptmodule file {filename}.")

    out = emb[0].detach().cpu().numpy()

    return out
```

I have tried a few different ways of passing in the model inside of trace, but am running into the same error.

I am looking for help in identifying what is causing this error and how I could go about resolving it.

Thanks